# KnockoutJS dynamic form validation

Tags: json, validation, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have a form that have a three field group that on a click of a "Add New" buttom other three field group will be added. That part is working great.

[image]

I want to add a validation so all three fields are required in order to add a new group.

For reference here is the code working: http://jsfiddle.net/5g8Xc/

```
var ContactsModel = function(contacts) {
    var self = this;
    self.contacts = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(contacts, function(contact) {
        return { firstName: contact.firstName, fathersLast: contact.fathersLast, country: contact.country };
    }));

    self.addContact = function() {
        self.contacts.push({
            firstName: "",
            fathersLast: "",
            country: ""
        });
    };

    self.removeContact = function(contact) {
        self.contacts.remove(contact);
    };
};
```

Any clue on how to implement this validation? I was trying to use jquery validation to do that but I think that is possible with KnockoutJS.

Appreciate any advice.

Comment: Check out Knockout validation https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation you define the validation in the view model.

Comment: The comment above qualifies for an answer to this question

Comment: I have implemented the validation but I always get valid! ANy clue? http://jsfiddle.net/8Hude/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated already, [the validation plugin](http://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation) will be the most elegant, less re-inventive solution.

**Edit:** After commentary [implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/5Cjye/) utilizing validation plugin

With that aside, you have a couple options.

- If you are confident the contact object will always contain only required fields, a not very robust implementation would be iterate over the properties of the contact ensuring each has some value.
- A little more robust, but still lacking the elegance of the plugin, implementation would be to maintain an array of required fields and use that array for validation. You can reference [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/8SKbk/) for this setup. Essentially, each required property is mapped to observables. Changes made to the value of any observable property triggers (via a `subscription`) a mutation call for a dummy observable that is used in a `computed`. This is required since a computed can't call `valueHasMutated`. The mutation call triggers the computed to reevaluate, thus updating the UI.

Comment: I could get this working but the new elements added doesn't track the validation... http://jsfiddle.net/8Hude/6/   Any Clue?

Comment: You were close. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/5Cjye/) is what you were after, I believe.

Comment: I fixed it. The issue was due to the contact being a `validated observable` rather than an actual `contact`. I simply encapsulated the isValid in a wrapper method within the contact object.

Comment: Hi, how can I show the errors when I press the Add New button? Right now its not working on the click of the button. Thanks a lot

Comment: Contact needs a `ko.validation.group(self).showAllMessages();` call. Added to the fiddle.